# IE10 developer console and hover events on inspect element

Tags: console, internet-explorer-10

Rather than change browser once again, anyone know a trick to allow this to happen:

I have a dropdown menu at the top of a website containing a settings button. When you hover over the settings button, the settings panel shows and when you hover off, the settings panel hides.

In chrome, if I use developer console to inspect that settings panel, when I hover over the settings button, the settings panel pops up and I can inspect elements inside it.

In IE10, when I hover over the settings button, it just inspects the text rather than bringing up the settings panel.

Any ideas on how to get IE10 to allow the hover over events to trigger so I can in fact inspect the elements inside the menu.

[image]

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Agh, I have to make it display:block before doing it... It's quite frustrating lol! I'm begging for someone else to have a special hot key to stop it happening lol.

Comment: Nope...still a problem. One must alter the DOM in memory just to be able to inspect these 'hidden' element in IE. It's really unfortunate that the tools are built 'for developers' don't really take some of the most important little things into consideration.